Como crear una tabla con botones en JavaScript los botones tiene como url una vista y envian parametros
En cada registro le agrego 3 botones: detalles, modificar y eliminar. Cargo la tabla la primera vez correctamente, pero después tengo la opcion de filtrar datos, con un select, en el evento change voy a la base de datos, limpio el tbody y lo cargo con los nuevos datos. Esto lo hago con ajax, y aquí es donde se borran los botones.
Me cuesta trabajo crearlos de nuevo con ajax por los parametros e imagen que llevan los botones.
<a class="btn btn-info info_especial" 
  href="{% url 'inst_detalle' oinst.rfc_empresa oinst.inst_clave %}"
  title="Ver Detalles de Instalación">
  <i class="bi bi-person-bounding-box"></i>
</a>



Con los datos aportados solo podemos animarte a arreglarlo, pero no ayudarte a ello, pues carecemos de un [example] que nos permita reproducir tu problema, y siendo así sólo podemos adivinar lo que no vemos, lo cual es arto dificil dadas las numerosas posibles variantes que tu código puede tener. Mejora tu pregunta siguiendo las pautas del enlace anterior, por favor, y conseguirás mejores ayudas.

hola no comprendo que es lo que esperas de parte de la comunidad ... es como que no sabes como hacer algo o buscas recomendaciones ... pero a partir del codigo compartido y la imagen no podemos hacer mucho mas que comentarte cosas ...

si estas en ajax y la respuesra de tu backend es un json ... puede usar javascript para re armar el html y mostrarlo... crea botones con javascript es lo mas facil del mundo ...
